# view enlarged image ontop of content on mouseover with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, onmouseover, onmouseout

I am trying to use javascript to show a larger version of my image on mouseover. I have the functionality working however the display property is not right and I need the image to be shown ontop of the page content i.e like a popout.

How an I add this to my code. The problem I have is that my page is divided into columns so the image is restricted by the width of the column so I need a way to override that i.e. use a popout.

[DEMO - js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/moragw5/2rt836co/1/)

html:

```
<div class="column1">
<div class="enlarge">
<img id="test" src="example.jpg" onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" width="400" height="300" class="img-responsive" alt="image">
<div id="test1" class="test1" style="display:none;">
<img width="800" src="example.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="column2">
A LOT OF TEXT IN HERE
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function bigImg() {
            $("#test1").show();
        }

        function normalImg() {
            $("#test1").hide();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be restrictive to code your script using specific elements (IDs). Would advice you to use element classes instead.

You can achieve what you want several ways, here is one using absolute positioning for the big image:

```js
$('.small-image').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
  $(this).siblings('.big-image').show();
}).on('mouseleave', function(e) {
  $(this).siblings('.big-image').hide();
})
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.row::after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.column {
  float: left;
}
.column1 {
  width: 20%;
}
.column2 {
  width: 80%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.enlarge {
  position: relative;
}

.big-image {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column column1">
    <div class="enlarge">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/" class="small-image" alt="image">
      <div class="big-image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column column2">
    A LOT OF TEXT IN HERE
  </div>
</div>
```

Also on **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2rt836co/5/)**.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for but I still can't get it to work...I'm not sure where to place the javascript code

Comment: Put it inside [dom-ready function](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). Elements must exist in DOM tree when the Javascript compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the img tag outside of the column1 div and then it will no longer be restricted.

If the img is not showing ontop of the text try add css value z-index.

```
img {
z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: thanks, its not restricted anymore. Can I make it so that it doesnt move all the content down the page to make room for itself? i.e. I would need a display element which will show the image on top on the existing content

Comment: if you add float:left to the img that will appear it will take it out of the context of the page so it should sit on top of the text.

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
$("#test" ).hover(function() {
  $("#test1").show();
},function(){
    $("#test1").hide();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2rt836co/4/